# How to map this to something readble in Java?

Tags: string, mapping

How do I map : "10%3A23%3A54+Apr+23%2C+2010+PDT" to something readable in Java ?

Frank

Comment: Could you give as an example of the desired output?

Comment: This is what you want, correct? 10:23:54 Apr 23, 2010 PDT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`URLDecoder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html) class.